# Change order of Title tag in moodle login page

Tags: moodle

Currently Moodle add Content-Type meta Tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

after Title tag

```
<title>Mount Orange School: Log in to the site</title>
```

within Head tag.

```
<head>
    <title>Mount Orange School: Log in to the site</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://school.demo.moodle.net/theme/image.php/boost/theme/1511289361/favicon" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
...
...
</head>
```

How can we change this order with minimum change in moodle3.1 core(https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/MOODLE_31_STABLE/login/index.php#L374). Putting Content Type meta tag on top within Head tag. Something like this.

```
 <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Mount Orange School: Log in to the site</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://school.demo.moodle.net/theme/image.php/boost/theme/1511289361/favicon" />
    ...
    ...
    </head>
```

We are using http://nutch.apache.org/ and it is not reading title if Content type Meta is not defined as first tag in Head.

[image]

Ref1: view-source:https://school.demo.moodle.net/login/index.php

Ref2: https://school.demo.moodle.net/login/index.php

Ref3: https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/MOODLE_31_STABLE/login/index.php#L374

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of doing it.

1. Change the core code here https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/MOODLE_31_STABLE/theme/bootstrapbase/layout/columns1.php#L30
2. Create Custom theme and import base theme and make changes there.

https://edwiser.org/blog/create-child-theme-moodle/

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Themes

Change which require is

```
<head>
    <title><?php echo $OUTPUT->page_title(); ?></title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $OUTPUT->favicon(); ?>" />
    <?php echo $OUTPUT->standard_head_html() ?>
.....
```

to

```
<head>
    <?php echo $OUTPUT->standard_head_html() ?>
    <title><?php echo $OUTPUT->page_title(); ?></title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $OUTPUT->favicon(); ?>" />

....
```